# Access from C++ to ListElement (QML) color

Tags: c++, properties, qml

I try to get access to properties of ListElement (QML):color;

```
ListModel {
    id:myListModel
    ListElement {name:"one" ;color:"red";objectName:"first"}
    ListElement(name:"two";color:"green"}
}
```

in C++ i have to use:

```
QObject* o=ui->declarativeView->rootObject()->findChild<QObject*>("first");
  o->setProperty("color","blue");
```

But i can not get access to this properties.
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ListModel` is not parsed as typical QML, but rather uses a custom parser to process the ListElement declarations.  This allows the model to avoid creating expensive objects for every data element.  `ListModel` has a number of functions available to manipulate the model data via QML.  You can add your own functions to the model in QML which you can access from C++, e.g.

```
ListModel {
    id:myListModel
    objectName: "model"
    function setColor(index, color) {
        myListModel.setProperty(index, "color", color)
    }
    ListElement {name:"one";color:"red"}
    ListElement {name:"two";color:"green"}
}
```

and in C++:

```
QObject* o=ui->declarativeView->rootObject()->findChild<QObject*>("model");
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(o, "setColor", Q_ARG(QVariant, 0), Q_ARG(QVariant, "yellow"));
```

Comment: So, ListModel's "setProperty" is not itself accessible from C++ because of the conflicting name?

Comment: There isn't a public C++ API for ListModel, so while you may be able to access the invokable methods of that object it's not recommended as they could change in the future.